# What do you call a member of a federation?

Tags: single-word-requests

I'm wondering if there is a more specific word than "member".

Comment: A *federale*, of course.

Comment: @DanBron [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Federales) says "The singular "Federale" is in fact incorrect, since the Spanish language uses "es" to pluralize nouns ending in a consonant; therefore, the correct singular form is "Federal" (with stress on the last syllable, unlike the English adjective), though this term is ambiguous in written English." But good joke.

Comment: The 50 states in the USA are member of a federation, which is the USA.  Likewise the 10 provinces of Canada, although that federation is organized rather differently.  And the cantons of Switzerland (I think those actually each have their own separate naturalization laws, just as each state in the USA has its own separate criminal code and marriage laws, etc.). Is there just one common noun that means any such state, province, or canton? Even the words "state" and "province" have other meanings that do not refer to members of a federation.  In German there is a word: ......

Comment: .... "Bundesstaat".  It's a compound of a word that means "federal" and a word that means "state", and it seems to mean any state that is a member of a federation, like the 50 states in the USA or the 16 states of Germany.  People persist in translating it into English by using the phrase "federal state", which is silly at best.

Comment: Despite the compelling answer, I do not think any such singular noun applies to modern English. Being alive during the formation of the U.S.A. Noah Webster certainly should have known of such a word and only describes federate in the adjective form in his 1828 dictionary and due to spelling reform, I think it's the oldest applicable one too. Wildcard searches starting with fed or confed do not help much. The 1913 dictionary suggests confederate is applicable (federation is just short for confederation) but that's just as if not more likely to be interpreted as a person without further context.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A *federate* (adjective used as noun)

*Adj* federate - united under a central government (the free dictionary online)

Also, as an analogy to the noun *confederate*

3. a person, group, nation, etc., united with others in a confederacy; ally

EDIT: the *Oxford English Dictionary* gives examples as a noun. But it says the word is chiefly *hist*, which I take to mean *historical* (talking about *history*).

Obviously a word is a word. You can choose to use it not. The following are just some of the examples.

> **federate, adj. and n.**
>
> 1. Each of the parties to a covenant or treaty; (later) spec[ifically] an ally bound by treaty. Now chiefly hist[orical].
>
> 1991   *Jrnl. Theol. Stud.* 42 346   Emperors..increasingly relied upon barbarian **federates** and tribal contingents and upon the great barbarian generals who recruited and commanded them.
>
> 2014   M. Rihan *Politics & Culture of Umayyad Tribe* ii. 43   Byzantium interacted with three major groups of Arab **federates**, allies of Byzantium, in the course of three centuries.

and also

Comment: My colleague and I were discussing if "federate" is the right word, which is what prompted me to post this question. It sounds right, but we weren't able to find any dictionary listing that says it can be used as a noun, nor any online examples where it is used that way. I really like "confederate". I wonder if it would be confusing to say "2 confederates of the federation" in a sentence.

Comment: I have edited my answer. The OED confirms that it has been and still is used as a noun, although apparently nowadays it is used "chiefly" to talk about history. Maybe you can edit your question and add an example *complete* sentence that you might wish to write.

Comment: That's exactly what I was looking for. We didn't have a particular sentence in mind, we were just discussing the word "federation" and were curious if there was a specific word for a member. Thanks for the detailed answer!